# UIAutomator - Screenshot after a failure

Tags: android, android-uiautomator, ui-testing

I'm new in Android Testing. I'm using UIAutomator to make some Black-Box testing. I would like to take a screenshot each time a test fails. I tried to use the `TestWatcher` class by adding a Rule in my test class. But, it doesn't work. I guess we cannot use the `@Rule` annotation when using UIAutomator.
There are lots of related topics for Espresso but I didn't find anything for UIAutomator.
Does anyone have a method to solve my issue?

Thanks!

Comment: is the answer below helping to figure out the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it in this way:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class TestClass {
  @Rule
  public ScreenshotTakingRule rule = new ScreenshotTakingRule();

  @Test
  public void yourTest() {
  
  }
}
```

and

```
/**
 * Junit rule that takes a screenshot when a test fails.
 */
public class ScreenshotTakingRule extends TestWatcher {
    @Override
    protected void failed(Throwable e, Description description) {
        Log.d(TAG, "taking screenshot..." + description.getMethodName());
        takeScreenshot(description.getMethodName());
    }

    private void takeScreenshot(String screenShotName) {
        ScreenCapture screenCapture = Screenshot.capture();
        try {
            screenCapture.setName(screenShotName);
            Set<ScreenCaptureProcessor> processorSet = new HashSet<>();
            processorSet.add(new SimpleNameScreenCaptureProcessor());
            screenCapture.process(processorSet);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "error while taking screenshot " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```